# Copy a file with dialog and also overwrite the file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Here are two lines of code:

```
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(sourceItemPath, destinationItemPath, FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs, FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(sourceItemPath, destinationItemPath, True)
```

I am wanting to copy a file with the Windows dialog, that the first line accomplishes. However, if the file exists, I am wanting the file to be overwritten.

The second line overwrites the file if it exists, yet does not show the dialog.

How can I copy the file with the dialog and also overwrite the file if it exists?

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem? Showing the dialog gives the *user* the choice of what to do. Do you want to overwrite the file, even if they say not to? If so, run with the second option. If not... what are you asking?

Comment: I've never used this dialog but I am guessing it shows a progress. Perhaps he wants to show the user the progress of the file copy, but it's not optional if they overwrite?

Comment: @Origin Ahh, yeah, gotcha. I forgot about the progress dialogs. +1 to your answer in that case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply erase the file if it exists and then call the `CopyFile` without the flag, because an overwrite will not be necessary.

Comment: That is what I have decided to do. I was wondering if there was a flag to set the option to auto overwrite, but sadly no.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know that doesn't work with the builtin windows copy dialog, as it's designed to let the user decide what to do in case of conflicts.

That's the reason why the CopyFile() method can be called either showing the dialog or silently with the overwrite flag.

I guess you have to implement a custom dialog by yourself to achieve what you want.